# How do I display a list of previous guesses before a user guesses a new number, using an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am creating a guessing game. I need to display the users' previous guesses every time the user makes another guess. I am using an array and pointers. The code below only displays the most recent thing entered by the user. I need it to display a list of previous inputs. The part of the code that includes the pointer seems to be where my issue is located, but I don't know exactly where?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void arrayTable(int[]);
int reviewGuess(int Answer, int userGuess);
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

int guessNum = 3; // Declares how many guesses the user can take.
int userGuess = 0;
int Answer;
char Choice;

int *pointer = NULL;

srand(time(NULL));
Answer = rand() % 20 + 1;  //Gives a random number ranging from 1 to 20
do{

    int x;
    cout << "          ____________________________________________________\n";
    cout << "          |                                                  |\n";
    cout << "          |  I want to play a game                           |\n"; // Displays a welcome message
    cout << "          |  I am thinking of a number between 1 through 20. |\n";
    cout << "          |  Can you guess the number in less than " << guessNum << " tries ? |\n";
    cout << "          |            Press '1' to play.                    |\n";
    cout << "          |       Press '2' if you want to EXIT!!!           |\n";
    cout << "          |__________________________________________________|\n";
    cin >> x;
    switch (x)
    {
    case 1:
        for (int i = 0; i < guessNum; i++) //Counter, for loop, stops when condition is met.
        {
        cout << " This is guess# " << i + 1 << " : "; //Takes the user input
        cin >> userGuess;

        int guessNum = 1;
        pointer = new int[guessNum];
        for (int i = 0; i < guessNum; i++) //Store the user guesses
        {

            *(pointer + i) = userGuess;

        }
        cout << "Here is a list of your guesses" << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < guessNum; i++)               // Display the user guesses.
        {

            cout << " Guess# " << i + 1 << " is " << *(pointer + i) << endl;
        }



        reviewGuess(Answer, userGuess); //Calls the function
        }

        cout << " ------------------>             <----------------------\n";
        cout << " ------------------> You Lost!!! <----------------------\n";
        cout << " ------------------>             <----------------------\n";
        cout << " You have exceeded the amount of guesses you were given.\n";
        cout << " The correct Answer is : " << Answer << endl;

        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "-------------->Thank You.\n";
        cout << "-------------->Have a good day.\n";

        break;

        system("pause");
        return 0;
        }

cout << "would you like to play again (y/n)?"; 
cin >> Choice;
} while (Choice == 'y');
system("pause");
return 0;
}

int reviewGuess(int Answer, int userGuess)
{
if (userGuess != Answer)
{
    if (userGuess > Answer)

        cout << " ----->   1 \n";
    else 
        cout << " ----->  -1 \n";
}
else
{
    cout << " ----->  0 \n";
    cout << " Good JOb, you have guessed the right number. \n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! This is a lot of code...can you narrow it down to an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Sometimes the very act of doing so will make the answer obvious to you, and in the very least, it makes it easier for us to find it. :)

Comment: ^ a crucial skill that you will need to learn anyway ("debugging"!)

Comment: `pointer = new int[guessNum];` allocates an array of one element every time. The two `for` loops that follow fill that array with the most recent guess, and then display it. It makes no sense to have an array of one element here.

Answer (score 0):

review the changes, and don't just copy and paste.

1. to access pointer array members, you can use the index [].
2. you are already in a for loop, so you dont want to create another for loop getting input, that would be 3 x 3 requests for data.
3. you were storing the data into an int, not into the array you created with pointer.
4. pointer isn't a very good name, when its an array of guesses. try calling it something more readable.
5. once it ran, if the user won, it still triggered losing code. you need to break out before accessing that code the way you have it set up. i created a bool, and changed your reviewguess method to return a bool whether they won or not. break out on exiting. note the double use of breaks; its in a for loop in a switch. you have to break out of the foor loop, and then break out of the switch. you cannot just put it after the for loop, as it will then keep asking for input if they win, and then report they won at the end.
6. note the use of the global constant to keep track of how many guesses. you were declaring and initializing the same variables all over the place. initialize with the type keyword once, at the start, and if you need the variable in the loop, initalize it before the loop so you dont try to reinitialize every iteration.
7. logic was reversed as far as higher or lower with reviewGuess
8. Not a bad start, keep your head up, and i hope i could help you out! 
   this is my first time answering a question.

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;


void arrayTable(int[]);
bool reviewGuess(int, int);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const int MAX_NUMBER_GUESSES = 3;// Declares how many guesses the user can take.
    int currentGuessNum = 0; 
    int userGuess = 1;
    int Answer;
    char Choice;
    int x;
    int *arrGuesses = NULL;
    bool gameWon = false;

    srand(time(NULL));
      //Gives a random number ranging from 1 to 20
    do {
        Answer = rand() % 20 + 1; //Gives a random number ranging from 1 to 20
                        //you want this in the loop otherwise you always have same answer

        cout << "          ____________________________________________________\n";
        cout << "          |                                                  |\n";
        cout << "          |  I want to play a game                           |\n"; // Displays a welcome message
        cout << "          |  I am thinking of a number between 1 through 20. |\n";
        cout << "          |  Can you guess the number in less than " << MAX_NUMBER_GUESSES << " tries ? |\n";
        cout << "          |            Press '1' to play.                    |\n";
        cout << "          |       Press '2' if you want to EXIT!!!           |\n";
        cout << "          |__________________________________________________|\n";
        cin >> x;
        switch (x)
        {
        case 1:
            userGuess = 1;
            arrGuesses = new int[MAX_NUMBER_GUESSES];
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_NUMBER_GUESSES; i++) //Counter, for loop, stops when condition is met.
            {
                cout << " This is guess# " << userGuess << " : " << endl; //Takes the user input
                cin >> arrGuesses[i];
                cout << "Here is a list of your guesses" << endl;

                for (int i = 0; i < userGuess; i++)               // Display the user guesses.
                {

                    cout << " Guess# " << i+1 << " is " << arrGuesses[i] << endl;
                }

                gameWon = reviewGuess(Answer, arrGuesses[i]); //Calls the function
                if (gameWon)
                {
                    break;
                }
           userGuess++;
            }
            if (gameWon)
            {
                break;
            }
            cout << " ------------------>             <----------------------\n";
            cout << " ------------------> You Lost!!! <----------------------\n";
            cout << " ------------------>             <----------------------\n";
            cout << " You have exceeded the amount of guesses you were given.\n";
            cout << " The correct Answer is : " << Answer << endl;

            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "-------------->Thank You.\n";
            cout << "-------------->Have a good day.\n";

            break;


            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }


        cout << "would you like to play again (y/n)?";
        cin >> Choice;
    } while (Choice == 'y');
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool reviewGuess(int Answer, int userGuess) 
{

    if (userGuess != Answer)
    {
        if (userGuess < Answer)

            cout << " ----->   1 \n";
        else
            cout << " -1 <-----  \n";
        return false;


    }
    else
    {
        cout << " ----->  0 \n";
        cout << " Good JOb, you have guessed the right number. \n";
        system("pause");
        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: i just realized this code actually has a memory leak; we keep declaring a new array arrGuesses = new int[MAX_NUMBER_GUESSES]; within the loop; that should be placed above the do{}while loop. every iteration we create a new array, drop the old one, and that memory is not deallocated. you would need to use the delete[]arrGuesses after each iteration to not have a memory leak, or as i originally said, move the creation to before the do while loop. you can just keep rewriting the data in the array rather than creating new arrays

Comment: Thank you so very much for the help. I believe what I did wrong is I used a pointer when I really just needed an array. I am really passionate about programming, and this was a school assignment. Two of the requirements were to use a 'const int' and a 'pointer' which I did. I already submitted the assignment about a week ago, before I submitted here, on StackOverflow. It just bothered me that the program was not giving me the desired results, so I submitted it here, so I could obtain some input from all you fine folks. So once again, thank you.

Comment: At the top I see "Int currentGuessNumber = 0", but I don't see it being used anywhere in the code. Am I missing something, is there a reason for it?

Comment: you're correct, that can be removed. I ended up just using the for instantiated counter variable i to keep track of that. a pointer can be used like an array, with the added benefit of being able to dynamically create it. you can ask the user how many guesses they want, and then create the array of the proper size and the code would work on the new array. i think the assignment wanted you to gain familiarity with creating pointers and using them as arrays :)